# jQuery Image Rollover in Magento CMS Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, wysiwyg

I have a few icons on a CMS page in Magento.  When I hover them, I'd like them to turn blue.  I'm using the following script to change the image on hover:

```
$(function() {
    $("#icons img")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_bl.png";
            $(this).attr("src", src);
         })
        .mouseout(function() {
             var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_bl.png", ".png");
             $(this).attr("src", src);
        });
});
```

This worked when I built the page outside of Magento.  Since I used the WYSIWYG image insert, the img src looks like this:

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/support/icons/faq.png"}}" alt="Frequently Asked Questions" />
```

When I hover the image, I get a console error of:

```
GET http://www_bl.png/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

How can I adjust the JavaScript to account for the different src format?

Comment: This question needs clarification.  The image source that you show is how it looks in the magento admin.  But if you view source of the CMS page in question on the front end of magento in your browser, you should get something that looks more like a normal image source.

Comment: @sconnie - Thank you for your response.  Before hovering, the image source looks like this:
    `src="http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/media/wysiwyg/support/icons/replacement.png"`

After hovering, it changes to: `src="http://www_bl.png"`

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  I'm sure that when you were testing outside of Magento, your img src path was relative and the only '.' was before the .png.  Then when you test in Magento, the first '.' that the regular expression finds is after the 'www', so that's why the src path becomes www_bl.png.

Comment: Nowadays, programmers usually do this with sprite images, a good example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9B2Bn/8/  This way, it can be done with only css and no jquery is required - and performance is faster!  It will require that you stack your two images into one over the other and then the css changes the position on hover.  hth, sconnie